# How to lookup i18n translations in nested yaml file in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

Under [4.1.4 "Lazy" Lookup](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), if you have the following dictionary:

```
es:
  books:
    index:
      title: "Título"
```

you can look up the books.index.title value inside app/views/books/index.html.erb template like this (note the dot):

```
<%= t '.title' %>
```

But if I alter the dictionary like this:

```
es:
  books:
    index:
      title: "Título"
      author:
        first_name: "Jane"
```

Then:

```
<%= t '.first_name' %>
```

gives a missing translation error.

1)  Is there a limit on the nesting depth you can have?
2)  Can you setup custom hash keys via yaml (for example, suppose instead of "index" as a key I want to use "kite", even though kite is not an actual view) and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no limit on the nesting depth, it's only that you're not following the "logic" behind it:

the '.' in '.first_name' refers to the controller + action in your page, in this case books: index: - so if you want to access author: first_name:, you should put '.author.first_name' in your index file.